# Send data through ajax to controller in yii

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, yii

First of all thanks all for your help, it's very useful. Im starting with yii and Im a bit lost yet.

I have create a jquery script where I validate a form and then I send it to my controller to work with it and save in the db.

But Im doing it wrong I think I cant connect with my controller. Here is the code:

Jquery script(after all the validate stuff, the variables are fine):

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/proceso/guardarproceso",
            data:
            {
            post_nombre: nombre,
            post_empresa: empresa,
            post_fechaI: fechaI,
            post_fechaF: fechaF,
            post_descripcion: descripcion
            },
            success: function(result)
            {
            alert(result);
            }
        });
```

And my controller     `ProcesoController`:

```
public function actionGuardarProceso(){

            $nombre = $_POST['post_nombre'];
            $empresa = $_POST['post_empresa'];
            $fechaI = $_POST['post_fechaI'];
            $fechaF = $_POST['post_fechaF'];
            $descripcion = $_POST['post_descripcion'];

            echo $nombre;
    }
```

Im not working with the db yet, I only want to see if I have done it well and the    `alert(result)`        shows me the content of      `$nombre`, but instead of that the alert shows me all the html code of the view(yes all xD)

I have done it too:

```
public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array(
                  'allow',
                  'actions'=>array('index','guardarproceso'),
                  'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
       );
    }
```

But nothing...

Anyone cuold help me or give me some idea? Thank you all again

Comment: Add action in create and update  key and give proper name to function'actions'=>array('create','update','guardarProceso'),

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a ajax or jquery result prints the html of the page its usually a error in the url. 
check your network jumps to see if it goes to the controller action you want. 
also baseurl is slower than createUrl. try Yii::app()->createUrl and edit that until it goes to the correct destination.. But the base of my theory is that your url is incorrect.

Comment: yes that was the error, the url wasnt defined well. I set an absolute path, thanks all for the help

Answer (score 1):

1st error: `url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/proceso/guardarproceso",`

replace `guardarproceso` with `guardarProceso`

2nd error:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```

`dataType` is missing; it should be `json`

read here http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

also, in the controller action `actionGuardarProceso`, use:

`echo json_encode(array('key'=>$nombre));
exit`

Comment: Thanks for your help, I have done those changes but it still doesnt work

Comment: can you please see one of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56196185/unable-to-post-the-data-from-view-to-controller-in-yii2) related to it ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo Yii::app()->request->baseUrl; ?>/proceso/guardarproceso",
                data:
                {
                post_nombre: nombre,
                post_empresa: empresa,
                post_fechaI: fechaI,
                post_fechaF: fechaF,
                post_descripcion: descripcion
                },
            success:  function(result) {
               alert(result);
            },
            error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert('error::'+errorThrown);
            }
            });
```

first try this you will get post data or not

```
public function actionGuardarProceso(){
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
exit;

    }
```

if not getting any data , try with your model

```
  public function actionGuardarProceso(){
        $model = new modelname;
        echo $_POST['modelname']['post_nombre'];
       exit;

       }
```

else try with the following

```
 public function actionGuardarProceso(){
           echo Yii::app()->request->getPost("post_nombre");
         exit;

           }
```

i hope you will get now from the above any methods

Comment: can you please see one of my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56196185/unable-to-post-the-data-from-view-to-controller-in-yii2) related to it ?